# Bootstrap Toggle menu not closing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am having problem with the toggle menu in some of my pages but working fine on others.

Here is my home page where the toggle menu does not close in mobile view when touched outside the menu.

```
<?php include_once("shared/header.php") ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- header file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- content css below -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
  <!-- Footer css below -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">

  <!-- For div Effect -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>  
  <!-- For div Effect ends-->


  <!-- Search -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/search.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script> 
  <!-- Search ends -->

</head>
<body>
<!-- Content Section Start -->  
<content>

</br>
</br>
</br>

  <div><!-- Post A job Div-->
    <h5 class="text-dark alert alert-secondary" align=center>XZYS.&nbsp;
      <a href="Post A Job/postAJob.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Post a Job</a>
      </button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>(Xyz)</strong>
    </h5></br>
  </div> 
  <!-- Post A job Div-->



<!--   center search -->

  <div align="center">
    <form id="center2" >
      <input type="search"  maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]"  required>
    </form>
    </div>
   <!--  center search end -->
<!-- </div> -->

<div class="container"><!-- Container -->
  <h1 class=" text-dark mt-5 alert alert-secondary" align="center">Latest</h1></div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"><!-- Ad Posts -->
    <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-2 no-gutters col-md-4 col-sm-6 mt-4 grid cs-style-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="img04">
          <figcaption>
            <h3>Job</h3>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 no-gutters col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mt-4 grid cs-style-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="img04">
          <figcaption>
            <h3>Job</h3>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 no-gutters col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mt-4 grid cs-style-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="img04">
          <figcaption>
            <h3>Job</h3>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 no-gutters col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mt-4 grid cs-style-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="img04">
          <figcaption>
            <h3>Job</h3>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 no-gutters col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mt-4 grid cs-style-3">
      <li>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/background.jpg" alt="img04">
          <figcaption>
            <h3>Job</h3>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </div>

  </div><!-- Ad Posts ends-->
</div><!-- Container Ends -->
</content>

<script src="js/toucheffects.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php include_once("shared/footer.php") ?>
```

**And here is my header page, where the code for the toggle menu resides.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header.css">
  <script src="js/header.js"></script>

  <style>
    .bg-black {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    #signup {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="color: white">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-black">



  <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/center.jpg" alt="Logo"title="Home" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item ml-5">
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ml-5">
            </li>

             <a class="nav-item nav-link active" style="color: white;" href="index.php">[&nbsp;menu1&nbsp;]</a>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="internships/internships.php">menu2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" style="color: white" href="map page/samples/blackmap.php">menu3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " style="color: white" href="company page/company.php">menu4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " style="color: white" href="Talent/talent.php">menu5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" style="color: white" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
          </ul> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Login</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
                  <a id="signup" href="">T</a>
                  <a id="signup" href="">C</a>

                </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </div>

              <div class="dropdown" >
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info">Signup</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
                  <a id="signup" href=" ">T</a>
                  <a id="signup" href=" ">C</a>
                </div></div>

                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div>
                  <button type="button" title="" class="btn demo fa fa-instagram navbar-right btn-sm text-right ">&nbsp;Follow @</button>


                </div>
              </div>


  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

For other pages the menu seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your file. You have to remove all the links from the Header.php, Which are already included in the index.php file.

Remove all the Files links present in head section header.php,

....